Regex consonant mismatch
I am trying to use Python and regex to search for words that look in certain defined ways. Can anyone tell me why the following code returns the word "choosy" as part of the output? I thought I made sure "oo" should be followed by any amount of consonants and then a word boundary, not "sy".
Code:
import re

pattern = r'\b[b-df-hj-np-tv-zB-DF-HJ-NP-TV-Z]*oo([b-df-hj-np-tv-zB-DF-HJ-NP-TV-Z]*\b)'

# Example list of words
words = ["choosy", "book", "boot", "booze", "loose", "look", "foot", "moo", "food", "moose"]

# Find matches
matches = [word for word in words if re.fullmatch(pattern, word)]

print("Matches:", matches)

Output:
Matches: ['choosy', 'book', 'boot', 'look', 'foot', 'moo', 'food']

Tip: use https://regex101.com/ and select Python on the left side. The website will show you which patterns match and why- it is easier to understand when you have it visualised. Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28753493/create-a-python-regular-expression-regex-that-will-find-all-consonants-in-each-w for capturing all consonants correctly, which is the issue here.

That "sy" is "any amount of consonants and then a word boundary". What makes you think it isn't?

Thanks! I figured out from Khelwood's answer what was the issue. I now see that I accidentally included y in my consonant class.

s is in the range p-t and y is in the range v-z. So your [b-df-hj-np-tv-zB-DF-HJ-NP-TV-Z] character class matches the s and the y. If you don't want to match those characters, you're using the wrong character class in your pattern.
In particular, if you don't want to regard y as a consonant, you could replace v-z with v-xz (and V-Z with V-XZ).
